# Table only appears for a split second on button click

Tags: javascript, html

I have a button and a table on my webpage. I want to view the table when I click that button. I have tried it using javascript but the table only appears for a split second and then disappears. following is the code for my table:

```js
var button = document.getElementById('BtnNextInsured'); // Assumes element with id='button'

button.onclick = function() {
  var div = document.getElementById('tblContact');
  if (div.style.display !== 'none') {
    div.style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    div.style.display = 'block';
  }
};
```

```html
<button id="BtnNextInsured" class="btn btn-md btn-primary">Next</button> Table to show:

<table id="tblContact" class="table table-light table-borderless" style="display:none;">
  <tr>
    <td class="cellContent">
      <input id="txtEmail" class="txt" placeholder="Email" />
    </td>
    <td class="cellContent">
      <input id="txtCell" class="txt" placeholder="Cell Phone" />
    </td>
    <td class="cellContent">
      <input id="txtLandline" class="txt" placeholder="Landline" />
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td colspan="3" style="text-align: right">
      <button id="BtnNextContact" class="btn btn-md btn-primary">Next</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I don't understand what's wrong with my code. I am a beginner to javascript.

Comment: Your code seems to be working fine. Are you sure you aren't accidentally clicking it twice?

Comment: Youre mouse may be double-clicking check it here https://mousetester.com/

Comment: You should use an `addEventListener` instead of an `onclick` event that appends and not replaces an event. Last but not least you should read into `classList` and `toggle`: https://codepen.io/tacoshy/pen/jOegXJy

Comment: @MichaelM. yes i am sure i am not clicking twice, when i click button it does a postback and shows table for a split second

Comment: @AtifAli Why do you need to have the page postback? Whenever you postback the page reloads and the JavaScript is reset. If you really need to send data to the server, then use [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX) instead.

Comment: The behavior described is typical of clicking a submit button in a form. If the button is in a form,  try adding the attribute `type="button"` to the button's HTML, because the default type  is in fact `"submit"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as comments saying better using eventlistener.
with the eventlistene, you can use the event and like here stop it to avoid double click.
to appear disappear use a class 'hide' so you can toggle it, easier than than checking display none.

```js
const tableAppear = () => {
  document.querySelector('#BtnNextInsured').addEventListener('click', evt => {
    evt.stopImmediatePropagation();
    document.querySelector('#tblContact').classList.toggle('hide');
  });
}
window.addEventListener('load', tableAppear);
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button id="BtnNextInsured" class="btn btn-md btn-primary">Next</button> Table to show:

<table id="tblContact" class="table table-light table-borderless hide">
  <tr>
    <td class="cellContent">
      <input id="txtEmail" class="txt" placeholder="Email" />
    </td>
    <td class="cellContent">
      <input id="txtCell" class="txt" placeholder="Cell Phone" />
    </td>
    <td class="cellContent">
      <input id="txtLandline" class="txt" placeholder="Landline" />
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td colspan="3" style="text-align: right">
      <button id="BtnNextContact" class="btn btn-md btn-primary">Next</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```